# Mysql, Node, query within a query, how to populate property in map function from another query

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

Firstly, if anyone can edit my question title or question to make more sense, please do.

I have a node/express app making mysql queries with mysql.js. I have a query that looks up a table of questions and then runs a map function on the results.  Within that map function, I need to query another table, of answers, corresponding to each record in the questions table. The value I need is the number of answers to that question, ie the number of records in each answers table. I've tried all kinds of different examples, but nothing quite fits my case in a way that makes sense to me.  New at Node and Express, and even MySQL so having a hard time picking out quite what to.

I understand that the problem is the async nature of node.  getAnswersCount() returns "count" before the query finishes.  Below is my code.  Need some advice on how to achieve this.

The value 123 is assigned to count just to clarify the trace results.

```
app.get('/', (req, res) => {

db.query('SELECT * FROM questions LIMIT 0, 100',
  (error, results) => {
    if (error) throw error;

    questions = results.map(q => ({
      id: q.id,
      title: q.title,
      description: q.description,
      answers: getAnswersCount( q.id )
    }));

    res.send( questions );
  });

});

const getAnswersCount = ( id ) =>
{
  const tableName = 'answers_' + id;
  var count = 123;

  var sql = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${tableName}(
                          id int primary key not null,
                          answer varchar(250) not null
                      )`;

  db.query( sql,
    (error, results) => {
      if (error) throw error;
      //console.log( 'answers table created!' );
  });

  sql = `SELECT COUNT(*) AS answersCount FROM ${tableName}`;

  db.query( sql,
    (error, results) => {
      if (error) throw error;

      //console.log( count ); // will=123
      count = results[0].answersCount;
      //console.log( count ); // will = results[0].answerCount
  });

  // I know this code runs before the query finishes, so what to do?
  //console.log( count ); //still 123 instead of results[0].answersCount

  return count;
}
```

EDIT: After attempting various versions of Michael Platt's suggestion in his answer without success, I finally worked out a solution using Express callbacks and a promise, adding the answers values to the questions array afterwards:

```
app.get( '/', (req, res, next ) => {

  db.query('SELECT * FROM questions LIMIT 0, 100',
    (error, results) => {
      if (error) throw error;

        questions = results.map(q => ({
        id: q.id,
        title: q.title,
        description: q.description,
      }));

      next();
    });

}, (req, res ) => {
  questions.map( currentElem => {

    getAnswersCount( currentElem.id ).then( rowData => {
      currentElem.answers = rowData[0].answersCount;

      if( currentElem.id == questions.length ) res.send( questions );
    });

  });
});

const getAnswersCount = ( id ) => {
  const tableName = 'answers_' + id;

  var sql = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${tableName}(
                          id int primary key not null,
                          answer varchar(250) not null
                      )`;

  db.query( sql,
    (error, results) => {
      if (error) throw error;
      //console.log( 'answers table created!' );
  });

  sql = `SELECT COUNT(*) AS answersCount FROM ${tableName}`;

  return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
      db.query( sql, ( error, results ) => {
          if ( error ) return reject( err );
          resolve( results );
      });
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which database module you are using to connect to and query the database but you could make the method `async` and then await the response from the query like so:

```
const getAnswersCount = async ( id ) =>
{
   const tableName = 'answers_' + id;
   var count = 123;

   var sql = `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ${tableName}(
                      id int primary key not null,
                      answer varchar(250) not null
                  )`;

   var results = await db.query(sql);

   sql = `SELECT COUNT(*) AS answersCount FROM ${tableName}`;

   var count = db.query(sql)[0].answerCount;

   // I know this code runs before the query finishes, so what to do?
   //console.log( count ); //still 123 instead of results[0].answersCount

   return count;
}

app.get('/', async (req, res) => {
   db.query('SELECT * FROM questions LIMIT 0, 100',
      (error, results) => {
        if (error) throw error;
        questions = results.map(q => {
          const answerCount = await getAnswersCount( q.id )
          return {
             id: q.id,
             title: q.title,
             description: q.description,
             answers: answerCount
          }
        }));

    res.send( questions );
  });

});
```

I think that will give you what you want and run correctly but it might require a bit of tweaking.  You may need to `async` the function on the actual route itself as well and await the call for `getAnswersCount` but that should just about do it.

Comment: Using mysql.js.  I attempted something like that but I'm not sure how the await part works within my code.  I tried something like this in the map function... answers: await getAnswersCount( q.id ), but that throws an unexpected identifier error.

Comment: Edited to show to use `async/await` in the `app.get` call.  Let me know if there is still a problem.

Comment: Still get an unexpected identifier on getAnswersCount.  Seems to be because await is within the mapped function.  If I take my original code and make it ... map(async q => {.... then use the way you rewrote my map function the error goes away but I get an array of pending promises.  I think I might have to read up on promises and rewrite all this somehow.

Comment: Do the rewrite and run `Promise.all` and it should resolve the promises for you